# How to redirect in Laravel to an external website

Tags: laravel

I redirect the user to another (external) website, but Laravel keeps routing back to my app's URI. My controller code is

```
public function showClientSite($councilUrl)
{
    //return Redirect::to($councilUrl)
    Redirect::away($councilUrl);
}
```

what i get is  https://www.mywebsite/appname/public/http://www.clientwebsite.co.uk

But i want it to be http://www.clientwebsite.co.uk

Comment: Does `return Redirect::way('http://www.example.com')` work?

Comment: No it doesn't, it still gives me  https://www.mywebsite/appname/public/http://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

The redirect call in itself doesn't do anything - you need to return it from the function in order for Laravel to actually use it.

```
return Redirect::away($councilUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

Try

```
return Redirect::to('http://google.com');
```

or

```
return Redirect::away('http://google.com');
```

Away adds only Header and https status to response.
Does your $councilUrl have an http:// prefix?